# Haskell Check if custom data type is even

Tags: haskell, types

So I have this exercise with the following data type

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Read)
```

This can be used to represent a natural number, for example 2 = Succ (Succ Zero).
I implemented a function that checks if the number is even.

```
even :: Nat -> Bool
even x = count x `mod` 2 == 0

count :: Nat -> Int
count Zero = 0
count (Succ x) = 1 + count x
```

It works fine for Zero, but whenever I try for something different, such as count Succ Zero or count Succ (Succ Zero)

```
*Main> even Succ Zero

<interactive>:6:1: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Nat -> t' with actual type `Bool'
    * The function `evenN' is applied to two arguments,
      but its type `Nat -> Bool' has only one
      In the expression: evenN Succ Zero
      In an equation for `it': it = evenN Succ Zero
    * Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:6:1)

<interactive>:6:7: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Nat' with actual type `Nat -> Nat'
    * Probable cause: `Succ' is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of `evenN', namely `Succ'
      In the expression: evenN Succ Zero
      In an equation for `it': it = evenN Succ Zero
```

Comment: `even (Succ Zero)`

Comment: There's no need to convert to an `Int`. Hint: write mutually recursive `even` and `odd` functions.

Comment: Well if `Nat` is going to be a data type that you are going to stick with for a whiile then i guess you best write an `Enum` instance first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is *not* the function itself, but you call the function like:

```
 even Succ  Zero
```

or more verbose:

```
(even Succ) Zero
```

So you here call `even` with `Succ` as parameter, `Succ` is a function of type `Nat -> Nat`, not a `Nat` itself. In order to pass `Succ Zero` to even, you need to use brackets, like:

```
even (Succ Zero)
```

That being said, one does *not* need to first convert the Peano number to an `Int` in order to check if it is even or not. One can define such function inductively as:

1. `Zero` is even;
2. `(Succ Zero)` is *not* even; and
3. `(Succ (Succ x))` is even, if and only if `x` is even.

So we can implement this like:

```
even' :: Nat -> Bool
even' Zero = True
even' (Succ Zero) = False
even' (Succ (Succ x)) = even' x
```

or we can introducing a "helper" function `odd' :: Nat -> Bool`, and use mutual recursion:

```
even' :: Nat -> Bool
even' Zero = True
even' (Succ x) = odd' x

odd' :: Nat -> Bool
odd' Zero = False
odd' (Succ x) = even' x
```